# Parentheses followed by parentheses

Tags: c++

I am trying to understand what a piece of C++ code is doing, but know nothing about C.

I have a loop like this:

```
(_A[0])=eigenMatrix::Zero(_n, _n);

for(i=0; i<_n; i++){
    for(j=0; j<=i; j++) (_A[0])(j,i)=(_A[0])(i,j)=value[i*n+j];
}
```

A is a vector of eigenMatrix type: vector <#eigenMatrix> _A;

I think the first line is defining (_A[0]) as a zero n*n matrix, but I can't work out what the (_A[0])(j,i) part is doing, and can't find any reference to this kind of ()() phrase in c++.

Comment: Can't tell you anything without seeing the definition of `_A`.

Comment: I speculate overloading of the parenthesis operator to assign values to elements of the matrix.

Comment: C++ != C, by the way, so lack of C knowledge does not necessarily mean much. If `_A` is an array of class objects, then that class might implement `operator()`, which allows function style calls. Otherwise it might be an array of function pointers.

Comment: In C, the only way that that might work is almost certainly *not* what your C++ code is doing, so I've taken the liberty of removing it from the tags and your subject.

Comment: Thank you - as I said, total moron in C++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Operator Overloading**

In C++ you can respecify the meaning of various operators. For a `Matrix` class, it does make sense to define a meaning for parentheses:

```
double & Matrix::operator()(int row, int col) {
    return data[row][col];
}
```

would result in a `Matrix` object `_A[0]` from which elements can be obtained as in `_A[0](2, 2)`.

**lvalue Assignment**

An interesting detail in your example is the assignment to an *lvalue* -- you can see `_A[0](j,i)` is on the left-hand side. Such an assignment is possible because we return a reference (`double &`) to the inner representation `data`.

If you open the header file that provides you with `eigenMatrix` (or rather its base class), you will find a declaration of a reference (`&`) returned by some `Matrix::operator()` method.

**Why bother?**

It provides convenient access to matrix elements while at the same time providing more control than simply exposing the inner `data` directly. For example you could imagine checks like

```
double & Matrix::operator()(int row, int col) {
    assert((row >= 0) && (row < n_row) && (col >=0 ) && (col < n_col));
    return data[row][col];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this - looking in the header file, eigenMatrix is a redefinition of MatrixXf or MatrixXd from Eigen/Dense dependent on context

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why () are used around `_A[0]`. 
`_A[0](i,j)` probably just returns a reference to value in i-th row and j-th column or another way around. 

[Here](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialMatrixClass.html) you can see how this operator is used:

```
int main()
{
  MatrixXd m(2,2);
  m(0,0) = 3;
  m(1,0) = 2.5;
  m(0,1) = -1;
  m(1,1) = m(1,0) + m(0,1);
}
```

and just to make everythign clear that's how you declare such an object.

```
class Matrix
{
private:
float value[4][4];

public:
float& operator()(int i, int j)
{
    return value[i][j];
}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets break down this code.

so lets assume that this line:

```
(_A[0])=eigenMatrix::Zero(_n, _n);
```

is actually

```
A = eigen::Matrix::Zero(_n, _n);
```

I am making this assumption because

1. Only element 0 of `_A` is ever accessed.
2. I think maybe you are using the eigen Library.

The next part is then a little easier.

```
for(i=0; i<_n; i++){ // Loop from 0 to `_n` which is the size of the Zero Matrix. 
    for(j=0; j<=i; j++) // Loop from 0 to i, this means you are only accessing the
                        // lower left side of the matrix. 

                        i=0 -> [j=0, ... No Access
                        i=1 -> [j=0, j=1, ... No Access
                        i=_n -> [j=0, j=1, ... j=_n

         (A)(j,i) = (A)(i,j) = value[i*n+j];
```

The first part is redundant, you are assigning to yourself.

The second part ( = value[...]) is assigning the currently looked at matrix element to the same element but in a 2D array stored as a 1D vector called `value`.
}

Comment: This is useful, but I should point out this is only a snippet of the code, and other values of A are called later, e.g. as _A[2]=eigenMatrix::Identity(_n, _n)